# Export as Python script from ModelBuilder never completes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

The script below was exported from ModelBuilder and runs within ModelBuilder in about 7.5 seconds.

However when I export it and try to run it as a standalone script in either PyScripter or the default Python IDLE it creates a schema lock on the DB and never ends...I have let it run for an hour.

There is no error it simply never completes the task.

Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this or why it works in ModelBuilder but not as a standalone?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop with a Basic level license.

```
    import arcpy

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    # Local variables:
    Wells_csv = "c:\\xx\\Wells.csv"
    Wells_Layer = "Wells_Layer"
    wells = "c:\\xx\\wells"

    # Process: Make XY Event Layer
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Wells_csv, "Surface_Longitude", "Surface_Longitude", Wells_Layer, "GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1927',DATUM['D_North_American_1927',SPHEROID['Clarke_1866',6378206.4,294.9786982]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98305509728916E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision", "")

    # Process: Copy Features
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Wells_Layer, wells, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Answer (score 1):

The Help page entitled [Exporting a model to a Python script](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000031000000) lists a number of caveats when using this technique as an aid to learn Python/ArcPy.

I far prefer to run tools manually via their tool dialogs and then to use Geoprocessing | Results to access Copy As Python Snippet and then Paste that well-formed code into a Python script instead.

In your case the script only uses two tools so I recommend running each from its tool dialog with the same parameters, and assuming it works, start writing a new script using Copy As Python Snippet.

If either tool fails to complete then this is a problem with the tool rather than ArcPy (or PyScripter/IDLE).

Comment: that's a good suggestion and attempted it....but now I have discovered that the `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management` is the problem when I run it from the toolbox it just runs and does not make any progress, but it works from model builder

Comment: @Dan I think you should research/ask about why Copy Features (after Make XY Event Layer) may not be working separately.  I would focus on the contents of that *.csv file.  For example, check whether all works when you reduce it to a few rows.

Comment: it works in model builder so I know it is not an issue with the CSV, the issue is now when I manualy use `Datamanagment>Features>CopyFeatures` or attempt to use it in a script

Comment: I've assumed that you have taken care not to have any schema locks around by closing all applications (rebooting to be absolutely sure) and then just running the script from IDLE.

Comment: I have but a schema lock would prevent the command form starting with an error, I can't even get an error its like I am stuck in an endless loop....I am  going to try to convert my created feature class to something else maybe a shape before sending it to the DB.

Comment: It's just a thought but have you tried changing `wells = "c:\\xx\\wells"` to `wells = "c:\\xx\\wells.shp"` - maybe that is what you are trying now.

Comment: I was able to do it manualy by right clicking on my layer that I created from  `MakeXY events` and using `Data>ExportData>` the outputting it to the db. How do I access that same tool in the toolbox?

Comment: Rather than trying to resolve why a two tool procedure is not working as a discussion in comments on an ArcPy question, can you ask it as a new question, please?

Comment: posted http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137719/arcpy-copyfeatures-management-not-working-in-python-or-manually