# Copy Features tool run after Make XY Event Layer on CSV file fails to complete?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, csv

Using the Make XY Event Layer tool I converted a table to a layer.

I am trying to convert the newly created layer to a feature class in my file geodatabase.

I have been able to do this in ModelBuilder but when I exported the model to a script and ran that it failed to complete - see [Export as Python script from ModelBuilder never completes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137712/export-as-python-script-from-modelbuilder-never-completes).

When run from its tool dialog it makes no progress and does not give an error (while in ModelBuilder it takes about 7.5 seconds for it to run).

I tried to convert the layer to a shapefile with `ConversionTools>ToShapefile` and get the same result.

Finally I right clicked the layer I created with `MakeXYEventLayer` and performed `Date>ExportData>Exported` it to my file geodatabase and it worked.

How do I get this to work via the tool dialog (so that it will then work in the Python script)?

Comment: Interesting, for a start you can skip ', "", "0", "0", "0"' in copyfeatures, if they're not populated just leave them out, if that doesn't work you could create the feature class manually and Append the events or Select, or Feature class to shapefile.. there's a few ways. Did you get an error message?

Comment: I removed the `', "", "0", "0", "0"'` and get the same results I'm looking for a solution that allows me to automate this work flow.

Comment: There are a few options to go from a layer to a feature class, for this one wells has no extension, you could try putting '.shp' on the end of it.. but it would help if there was an error message to see why it's failing, in these cases the problem is most likely in the CSV and not the tool.. Try FeatureClassToShapefile http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Feature_Class_To_Shapefile/00120000003m000000/ or Select http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000005000000 with no query.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137712/export-as-python-script-from-modelbuilder-never-completes - I think for this not to be a duplicate it needs to be edited to focus on just running the two steps from their tool dialogs as suggested (perhaps not clearly enough) in a comment on its earlier incarnation.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I've edited the question to try and separate the problem of the tool not completing from its dialog from the tool not completing from within a script.  The former will be what causes the latter so I'm trying to help the asker by teasing the source of the problem out from where its manifestation was first observed.  I'm not sure if you were aware of the earlier Q&A.

Comment: Not so much, or at least I don't remember it. I cringe every time I see an event layer from Excel or CSV - they're just too dodgy. I always convert to file geodatabase table/personal geodatabase table or (if I have no choice) dbf. Without an error message it's hard to see if this is the case; notwithstanding there are several ways to get features from one place to another - perchance one of the others might be more tolerant (provided the error doesn't originate from CSV)

Comment: I've run into a similar problem that was caused by the schema.ini file that arcgis creates when it opens a .csv. If I recall arcgis tries to guess field type when importing and stores it's guesses in the schema.ini. Check the column types it picks in this file. In my case it was putting numeric into txt columns because it couldn't handle null values in the csv.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a problem with the CSV file.

Possibilities include (but are not limited to):

- Spaces and/or non-alphanumeric characters in field names, or starting with underscore.
- Bad data in cells. Esri only reads the first few lines to decide the data type, if the first dozen or so are numbers it calls the field integer, if there's later a value like 'N/A' in the field then it has a spit!
- Duplicated field names, when shortened to 10 characters.
- 'reserved' field names: FID, SHAPE etc..
- Permission denied by OS

I have tested this on a table:

```
x,y,z,h,r,p,t
152.75815,-28.34317,2467.171222,204.403864,-0.215472,-4.31432,540751.6635
152.758058,-28.343492,2467.048023,204.305248,-2.287749,-4.916747,540752.2636
152.757997,-28.343707,2466.870526,204.225232,-3.082666,-5.08145,540752.6637
152.757951,-28.343868,2466.693121,204.137175,-3.269405,-5.160663,540752.9637
152.757921,-28.343976,2466.551302,204.07381,-3.172274,-5.225498,540753.1638
152.757891,-28.344084,2466.390267,204.015868,-2.910663,-5.244445,540753.3638
152.757847,-28.344247,2466.137704,203.965636,-2.264,-5.294325,540753.6639
152.757772,-28.344518,2465.655387,203.89813,-1.057936,-5.344787,540754.164
152.757699,-28.34479,2465.164517,203.946887,-0.757532,-5.433305,540754.6641
152.757639,-28.345007,2464.784946,203.900885,-0.882926,-5.508097,540755.0642
152.75755,-28.345335,2464.12202,203.710554,-1.899527,-5.6251,540755.6643
```

with the code:

```
import arcpy
inCSV=r'D:\some\path\OneRun_with_Header.csv'
outShp = r'D:\some\path\test'
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(inCSV,"x","y","Lyr")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Lyr",outShp)
```

and it works just fine. Have a closer look at your tabular data, there's bound to be a problem there. I did notice on your previous post:

```
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Wells_csv, "Surface_Longitude", "Surface_Longitude", Wells_Layer,
```

has "Surface_Longitude" for X and Y - this doesn't affect the tool too much but you'll end up with all your features on a 45degree slope with the same X and Y.

Comment: I thought the same thing except it creates a layer and works in model builder and it works with right clicking export...the csv is good

Comment: you're *absolutely* sure of that? There's nothing that's been 'fixed' in the layers by those other tools that you haven't checked? You've also changed the duplication of the X field? I feel that there are some field names that, when shortened to the max length of the shape file fields, are identical. What field names do you have in the CSV?

Comment: Yes..My headers are `API,Well_Name,Well_Suf,Op_Num,Btm_Fld,Spd_Dt,Btm_Ls_Num,RKB_Elv,BH_Total,Tr_Vrt_Dp,Srf_N_S_Ds,Srf_N_S_Cd,Srf_E_W_Ds,Srf_E_W_Cd,Srf_Area,Srf_Blk,Btm_N_S_Ds,Btm_N_S_Cd,Btm_E_W_Ds,Bt_E_W_Cd,Btm_Area,Btm_Blk,Ttl_Dp_Dt,St_Dt,Type_Code,Distr_Code,Stat_Code,Wtr_Dpth,Surf_Lon,Surf_Lat,Btm_Lon,Btm_Lat,Surf_Lse,Cmplx_ID,Strut_Num`

Comment: Where's surface_lonitude (and presumably surface_latitude)? It seems to me that your fields don't exist hence your error. In this table it's surf_Lat and surf_Lon.

Comment: `Surf_Lon,Surf_Lat` I modified it slightly. I spoke with ESRI tech support and they had me disable the `Background Processing` under `Geoprocessing Options` and it now works manually but they are still unsure why the script is not working (yes, I tried copying the python snippets), the problem is not in the CSV

Comment: Then I think that Esri Tech Support should handle this. Apart from importing the CSV to a database there's nothing more I can suggest, except for reading the file in python and creating the features on an insert cursor.